# Как правильно использовать файлы?

Tags: objective-c, разработка-игр, iphone, cocos2d

Только начал осваивать `Chipmunk template` в `Xcode`. С целью моделирования радиальной (планетарной-, осевой- ...) гравитации как с 0:12 здесь: [Zepi Free](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BxkbXfEWg4&feature=player_embedded)

Когда к центральному спрайту с разных сторон притягиваются спрайты, `Scott Lembcke` посоветовал воспользоваться шаблонами из проекта `ChipmunkShowcase`, в частности файлами: [Planet.c](https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk-Physics/blob/master/Demo/Planet.c) и [SolarSystemDemo.m](https://github.com/slembcke/ChipmunkShowcase/blob/master/Showcase/Demos/SolarSystemDemo.m).

Вопрос: как правильно использовать эти файлы с целью просмотреть результат их работы в симуляторе? Создать `MyLayer`: `CCLayer`, в нем `Space *space` или же использовать их как хедеры для `Mylayer` и потом копипастить туда код?

Прошу прощения за нубский вопрос, пока еще не разобрался как работает движок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С Chipmunk сталкивался всего один раз, когда кокос устанавливал :) а что похожее на ответ возможно лежит тут: [`Chipmunk inside class`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1296).

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос с примерами: [Chipmunk-Spacemanager](https://github.com/robertblackwood/Chipmunk-Spacemanager)